# Design bootstrap 3 page layout dynamically maintaining height, scroll, width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to design page layout by using bootstrap css. I have lost already four days but I cannot do perfectly. I am falling two problems like below:

1. **How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?**
2. **Scroll bar is underneath because of top nav bar not fixed.**

The image of my problem below:

[image]

I have used following code .........

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row row-one">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur molestie pharetra lacus, a tincidunt elit fermentum ac. Praesent ac mauris nisl. Cras aliquet imperdiet nunc, vestibulum faucibus urna laoreet eu. Aliquam pharetra leo ut mauris
            tempus dignissim. Aenean mollis dui sed orci hendrerit vitae hendrerit nisi convallis. Ut id libero a metus ullamcorper consectetur. Suspendisse sed risus erat. In pharetra velit condimentum nisl interdum sed iaculis mi consectetur. Pellentesque
            habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas vulputate consectetur urna, a dignissim odio vestibulum a.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-two">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur molestie pharetra lacus, a tincidunt elit fermentum ac. Praesent ac mauris nisl. Cras aliquet imperdiet nunc, vestibulum faucibus urna laoreet eu. Aliquam pharetra leo ut mauris
            tempus dignissim. Aenean mollis dui sed orci hendrerit vitae hendrerit nisi convallis. Ut id libero a metus ullamcorper consectetur. Suspendisse sed risus erat. In pharetra velit condimentum nisl interdum sed iaculis mi consectetur. Pellentesque
            habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas vulputate consectetur urna, a dignissim odio vestibulum a.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    padding: 0px 0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0px 0;
}

footer .navbar-inverse {
    background: #5f5f5f;
}
/*Prevent the Footer from Collapsing*/
footer .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

    footer .navbar-nav > li {
        float: left;
    }

        footer .navbar-nav > li > a {
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
/*END: Prevent the Navbar from Collapsing*/

.row-one {
    /*do not use display: table-row;*/
}

.row-two {
    /*do not use display: table-row;*/
}

.row-one > .col-xs-12 {
    background-color: gray;
}

.row-two > .col-xs-12 {
    background-color: bisque;
}

.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

**Precaution:**

1. Avoid display: table, table-row, and table-cell.
2. Avoid JavaScript code.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSnmxPDJmuUfFmLjvbFF?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with all those rules in place.

Comment: Nope. Even Bootstrap's own documentation adds CSS.

Comment: @Christina, Avoid display: table, table-row, and table-cell. and Avoid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

css should be for example

```
.row-one{
height:500px;}

.row-two{
height:500px;}
```

as that is the container of the text it would make them alot taller, obviously customise to your own needs